# Keep trying to install ecapture but gives me error every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I keep trying to install ecapture using `pip install ecapture` and `pip3 install ecapture` but it just keeps giving me this HUGE error. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Here is the link the the error https://pastebin.com/t1C8phiw

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: @DapperDuck The error is so big it won't let me because it exceeds the character limit...

Comment: @DapperDuck Here is the link https://pastebin.com/t1C8phiw

Comment: Downgrade to Python 3.8 and try again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error+C2039%3A+tp_print+is+not+a+member+of+_typeobject